# iphone - is it possible to do push notification service with adobe flash cs3?

Tags: iphone

just like in the title, is it possible to do push notification service with adobe flash cs3 ? *sending a push notification via flash to an iPhone, maybe in javascript?

Comment: With Flash, on the iPhone - what do you mean?

Comment: This question is unclear. Please use proper grammar and formatting to help potential answerers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, no. Push notifications require a server dedicated to Push Notifications. I have no idea what you're talking about when you say Flash CS3.